# Destination Unreachable (Port Unreachable) using Haskell

Tags: sockets, haskell, client-server

Using Wireshark to debug, I receive the following error when sending UDP packets on localhost:

```
Destination Unreachable (Port Unreachable)

Checksum: 0x0000 (Illegal)
```

I am constructing my server first on a port between 10000 - 15000 using

```
startServer :: Port -> IO Server
startServer port = withSocketsDo $ do
  -- Look up the server address and port information.
  addrs <- getAddrInfo (Just $ defaultHints { addrFlags = [AI_PASSIVE] }) Nothing (Just port)
  let serverAddress = head addrs

  -- Bind to the socket.
  sock <- socket (addrFamily serverAddress) Datagram defaultProtocol
  bindSocket sock (addrAddress serverAddress)

  -- Create the server and run the client send and receive threads.
  clients  <- newMVar $ createEmptyClients
  let server = Server sock port clients
  _ <- forkIO $ forever $ receiveClientJoin server
  return server
```

I am listening for new clients connecting via UDP using

```
-- | Connected a client to the server.
receiveClientJoin :: Server -> IO ()
receiveClientJoin server = do
  print "Receiving"
  (msg, _, clSockAddr) <- recvFrom (sSocket server) 4096
  print $ "Server received client join message: " ++ msg
```

And I am connecting to the server with clients using

```
connectToServer port = do
  -- Get the server's address and port information.
  addrInfo <- getAddrInfo Nothing (Just "localhost") (Just port)
  let serverAddr = head addrInfo
  sock  <- socket (addrFamily serverAddr) Datagram defaultProtocol
  sendTo sock "Hello from this client!" (addrAddress serverAddr)
```

Why are my clients' packets not finding the server?

Comment: Could you post a full, compiling, example?

Comment: It might be an ipv4 vs ipv6 issue. What happens if you use `127.0.0.1` instead of localhost?

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson Thanks! It works after changing to `127.0.0.1`. Could you briefly elaborate on why that was the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are listening on an IPv6 address and trying to connect to an IPv4 address.  This is actually a slightly common problem.  For example, I ran across this issue when working with `commsec`.

Consider the fragments where you discover your `AddrInfo`:

```
import Network.Socket 

main :: IO ()
main = do
  let port = "2474"
  addrs <- getAddrInfo (Just $ defaultHints { addrFlags = [AI_PASSIVE] }) Nothing (Just port)
  let serverAddress = head addrs
  print serverAddress

  addrInfo <- getAddrInfo Nothing (Just "localhost") (Just port)
  let serverAddr = head addrInfo
  print serverAddr
```

Now the output will vary by machine, but on one of my CentOS systems with both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses the output clearly shows the second (connect) address is IPv6 while the first (listen) address is IPv4:

```
AddrInfo {addrFlags = [AI_PASSIVE], addrFamily = AF_INET, addrSocketType = Stream, addrProtocol = 6, addrAddress = 0.0.0.0:2474, addrCanonName = Nothing}
AddrInfo {addrFlags = [AI_ADDRCONFIG,AI_V4MAPPED], addrFamily = AF_INET6, addrSocketType = Stream, addrProtocol = 6, addrAddress = [::1]:2474, addrCanonName = Nothing}
```

One solution is to force a particular version of IP via a hint or an address (ex. an IPv4 address as in my comment).  The hint solution is probably more desirable:

```
-- For servers:
  addrs <- getAddrInfo (Just defaultHints { addrFamily = AF_INET6
                                          , addrFlags = [AI_PASSIVE] })
                       Nothing (Just port)
-- For clients:
addrInfo <- getAddrInfo (Just defaultHints { addrFamily = AF_INET6 })
                        (Just "localhost") (Just port)
```